# Values turn up undefined in resolver (Graphql, Apollo, React)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

The resolver works fine when i use it from the Playground. But when i send values from the client to the resolver, values somehow show up "undefined" in the resolver.

Client:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { Form, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

function TestPage() {
    const userId = "5fa2c177382ce83660b3911b";

    const { loading, data: { getUser } = {} } = useQuery( FETCH_USER_QUERY, {
        variables: {
          userId
        }
    });

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        countryInput: '',
        descriptionInput: ''
    })

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    const [updateCountry] = useMutation(UPDATE_COUNTRY_MUTATION, {
        variables: {
        userId, 
        values 
        }
    })
    
    const submit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        updateCountry()
    }

    console.log(values)

      let TestPage;
      if(loading){
        TestPage = (<p>Page Loading...</p>)
      } else {
        const {
            username,
            country,
            description
        } = getUser;

        TestPage = (
            <Grid columns={1}>
            <Grid.Row className="profile-name">
                <h1>Test Page</h1>
                <h4>This page is for testing code</h4>
                <h4>User: {username}</h4>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row className="profile-name">
                <h1>Country: {country}</h1>
                <h1>Desc: {description}</h1>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row>
                <Form>
                    <input
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                    placeholder="Country"
                    type="text"
                    name="countryInput"
                    value={values.countryInput}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    />

                    <input
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                    placeholder="Description"
                    type="text"
                    name="descriptionInput"
                    value={values.descriptionInput}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    />

                    <button 
                    onClick={submit}
                    className="ui button red"
                    color="red"
                    >
                        Save
                    </button>
                </Form>

            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
        )
      }

    return TestPage;
}
```

Mutation (in the same file as client):

```
const UPDATE_COUNTRY_MUTATION = gql `
    mutation UpdateCountry( 
        $userId: ID!, 
        $countryInput: String, 
        $descriptionInput: String ){
        updateCountry(
            userId: $userId, 
            countryInput: $countryInput
            descriptionInput: $descriptionInput
        ){
            username
            country
            description
        }
    }
`;
```

I got "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400" before, but now it just returns nulls in the db.

I assume the issue was the mutation, i changed it from using "input" to just typing out the variables, but doesent work.

I googled around and tried different kind of doing callbacks and hooks, but i get the unhandled rejection error and when i get it working the values show up undefined.

How can the value be defined when sent in the client but show up undefined in the resolver? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: it's enough to test network request detaily ... 'values' variable passed, not required ones

Comment: I used the {error} on the useMutation, and i got the error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.", so i guess the values are passed as objects? I made the values required in the mutation. Still get the error.

Comment: different things ... react claims about rendering complex object ... again, check RAW (json) network request (body, in dev tools/network tab) - show it

Comment: {
 "operationName": "UpdateCountry",
 "query": "mutation UpdateCountry($userId: ID!, $countryInput: String!, $descriptionInput: String!) {\n  updateCountry(\n    userId: $userId\n    countryInput: $countryInput\n    descriptionInput: $descriptionInput\n  ) {\n    username\n    country\n    description\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
 "variables": {
  "userId": "5fa2c177382ce83660b3911b",
  "values": {
   "countryInput": "sdfkjhsdk",
   "descriptionInput": "sdlfjdsd"
  }
 }
}

Comment: do you see 'extra' `values` 'level' in `variables`?

Comment: Doesn't look like it no

Comment: `"variables": { "userId": "5fa2c177382ce83660b3911b", "values": { "countryInput": "sdfkjhsdk", "descriptionInput": "sdlfjdsd" } } }` should be  `"variables": { "userId": "5fa2c177382ce83660b3911b", "countryInput": "sdfkjhsdk", "descriptionInput": "sdlfjdsd" }  }`

Comment: I think it passes them like this because the values are passed inside the { }, in the variables in the useMutation, because when i send them without they show up individualy. The problem is the userId needs to be in { }, and i can't send them differently it seems

Comment: they must be passed individualy `useMutation(UPDATE_COUNTRY_MUTATION, {
        variables: {
        userId, 
        ...values 
        }`  to match mutation specs

Comment: It works! This is the 3rd time you save my ass. I need to send you a cake or something

Comment: I'll remember ... when I'm in DK ... I could write a solution at the beginning  but I hope you learned sth about graphql debugging ;)

Comment: I'm learning a lot haha. Thanks for the help, it is for my bachelor's project so i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

"...values" instead of "values" in the useMutation:

```
const [updateCountry] = useMutation(UPDATE_COUNTRY_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
       userId, 
       ...values 
       }
    })
```